# Simplify the Expression (factorization and notable product)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the expression:
$$ \frac{x^{4}+y^{4}}{x^{2}-2xy+2y^{2}} - \frac{(x+y)(x^{2011}+y^{2011}) } {(x^{2010}-x^{2009}y)} +x^{2008}y^2- ... + x^2y^{2008}-xy^{2009}+y^{2010} $$

It try this but i but I can't proceed from here:

$$ \frac{(x^{2}+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2}{x^{2}-2xy+2y^{2}} - \frac{(x+y)(x^{2011}+y^{2011}) } {(x^{2009}(x-y))} +x^{2008}y^2- ... + x^2y^{2008}-xy^{2009}+y^{2010} $$

Comment: The sum at the right is $x^{2008}y^2- ... + x^2y^{2008}-xy^{2009}+y^{2010}=\frac{x^{2011}+y^{2011}}{x+y}-x^{2010}+x^{2009}y\,$ but that alone doesn't simplify things much. What is the context and/or source of this problem?

Comment: Thanks Mark. for the hint. This exercises is from an internet forum but i don't see the solution.

Comment: Alternatives this question: a)x^2+y^2 b)2x^2+y^2 c)x^2+2y^2 d)x^2 e)y^2